# How to bulk rename files based on their content in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to prepend file information into the names of a set of .html files. But I've been getting a traceback error resulting in the same date being prepended into all of the files processed.

The intended outcome is to prepend the relative date from the  into the title of each html file.

```
2021-03-27-x.hmtl
2021-03-28-x.hmtl
2021-03-29-x.hmtl
etc
```

The script:

```
import os

dir = os.listdir(".")

files = []

for file in dir:
    if file[-5:] == '.html':
        files.insert(0, file)

for fileName in files:
    file = open(fileName)
    content = file.read()
    file.close()

    datetime = content.partition('datetime="')[-1][:10]

    [os.rename(f, datetime + "-" + str(f)) for f in os.listdir('.') 
    if ((not f.startswith('.')) and f.endswith(".html"))]

    print(datetime)
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../TEST.io/3prefixdate.py", line 25, in <module>
    file = open(fileName)
```

The code works for bulk processing files so I think that its likely the os.rename lines that are broken?

Comment: _I've been getting a traceback error_ Are we supposed to guess what it is?  Post the error.

Comment: Don't post tracebacks as comments. Edit your original question and paste (and format) it there.

Comment: "Traceback" is not a kind of error. It's the thing that goes with the error. *Literally* every error in Python will start by printing "Traceback (most recent call last)"

Comment: Before you do this, please note that you will be renaming EVERY FILE in the directory for  EVERY html file you find.  This is almost certainly not what you want.  You will end up with "2021-01-02-2021-01-03-2021-01-04-2021-01-05-2021-01-06-oldname.txt".

Comment: ...yeah...I'm guessing that you don't want to have the second loop, which is what that list comprehension near the end of your code really is.  I would strongly suggest that you not use list comprehensions (all that stuff between '[' and ']') to do arbitrary processing like what you're trying to do.  List comprehensions should be reserved for actually computing new lists.  Your code would be much more understandable if you used a `for` loop containing an `if` statement instead.  But you likely don't want that stuff in either form.

Comment: That traceback is incomplete.  It should have an actual error at the bottom.

Comment: I see, most of this code is made up of snippets from other people as I'm still a beginner. The multi file processing element works, so I'm wondering if there is a simple function to rename each targeted file?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ".html" - Apologies I think I have misunderstood a traceback error. I'm guessing this is irrelevant as the filenames are being prepended, just incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that you're looping through each of the files you want to process, but then you seem to be looping again, trying to rename all of the matching files in the directory once for each file that you process in the outer loop.  This doesn't make sense to me, especially given what you say you want as a result.

I'm guessing that this is kinda what you want.  I took the liberties of simplifying things a bit and using some more favorable Python idioms:

```
import os

files = os.listdir(".")

files = []

for file in files:
    if file[0] != '.' and file.endswith('.html'):
        files.insert(0, file)

for fileName in files:
    with open(fileName) as f:
        content = file.read()
    datetime = content.partition('datetime="')[-1][:10]
    os.rename(fileName, datetime + "-" + fileName)
    print(datetime + "-" + fileName)
```

If you're getting an error, I assume that it involves the extraction of the date from the file's content.  That's a fairly hairy expression, and of course, I have no way of knowing if it's right without knowing what the content of your files looks like.

A few comments on changes I made:

1. Don't use `dir` as a variable name.  It's a built-in Python function.  Note how in the display of the code in your question, the `dir`s are red.  That's why.
2. Learn to use `with` for working on files.  It prevents you from forgetting to close a file when you're done using it, and is visually superior too IMO.
3. `<string>.endswith()` is preferable here because it's possible that you'll see file names shorter than 5 characters, at which point `<string>[-5:]` will raise an Exception.

Comment: Then upvote and Green Check me baby ;) - glad I could help!